# Thread synchronization between data pointed by vectors of std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm pretty new to concurrent programming and I have a specific issue to which I could not find a solution by browsing the internet..

Basically I have this situation (schematic pseudocode):

```
void fun1(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SmallObj>>& v) {
  for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    .. read and write on *v[i] ..
}

void fun2(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SmallObj>>& w) {
  for(int i=0; i<w.size(); i++)
    .. just read on *w[i] ..
}


int main() {

 std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SmallObj>> tot;

 for(int iter=0; iter<iterMax; iter++) {
   for(int nObj=0; nObj<nObjMax; nObj++)
      .. create a SmallObj in the heap and store a shared_ptr in tot ..

   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SmallObj>> v, w;
   .. copy elements of "tot" in v and w ..

   fun1(v);
   fun2(w);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is operating concurrently spawning two threads to execute fun1 and fun2 but I need to regulate the access to the SmallObjs using some locking mechanism. How can I do it? In the literature I can only find examples of using mutexes to lock the access to a specific object or a portion of code, but not on the same pointed variables by different objects (in this case v and w)..

Thank you very much and sorry for my ignorance on the matter..

Comment: Just wrap the modify code in a mutex.  That way only one thread modifies at a time.

Comment: There's no law that requires a given mutex to only be used to lock a single object. You can create a mutex, and lock the same mutex any time you want to access anything related to your shared pointers. The End.

Comment: Will you only read/write the objects in the vectors or will you modify the vectors themselves? If the former, there is no need in copying the vectors. By the way: if you use std::thread without std::reference_wrapper, you get your copy anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to regulate the access to the SmallObjs using some locking mechanism. How can I do it?

Use getters and setters for your data members. Use a `std::mutex` (or a `std::recursive_mutex` depending on whether recursive locking is needed) data member to guard the accesses, then always lock with a lock guard.

Example (also see the comments in the code):

```
class SmallObject{

    int getID() const{
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m_mutex);
        return ....;
    }


    void setID(int id){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m_mutex);
        ....;
    }

    MyType calculate() const{
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m_mutex);

        //HERE is a GOTCHA if `m_mutex` is a `std::mutex`
        int k = this->getID();               //Ooopsie... Deadlock

        //To do the above, change the decaration of `m_mutex` from
        //std::mutex, to std::recursive_mutex
}

private:
    ..some data
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have thought to protect the access to the data member of `SmallObj` but I was wondering if the process of putting a lock in the sensitive scope would increase the overhead of the call. How much is it "expensive" to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to hold an `std::mutex` for the whole vector:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void fun1(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SmallObj>>& v,std::mutex &mtx) {
  for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    //Anything you can do before read/write of *v[i]...
   {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
        //read-write *v[i]
   }
   //Anything you can do after read/write of *v[i]...
}

void fun2(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SmallObj>>& w,std::mutex &mtx) {
  for(int i=0; i<w.size(); i++) {

   //Anything that can happen before reading *w[i] 
   {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
        //read *w[i]
    }
    //Anything that can happen after reading *w[i]
}


int main() {

 std::mutex mtx;
 std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SmallObj>> tot;

 for(int iter=0; iter<iterMax; iter++) {
   for(int nObj=0; nObj<nObjMax; nObj++)
      .. create a SmallObj in the heap and store a shared_ptr in tot ..

   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SmallObj>> v, w;
   .. copy elements of "tot" in v and w ..

   std::thread t1([&v,&mtx] { fun1(v,mtx); });
   std::thread t2([&w,&mtx] { fun2(w,mtx); });

   t1.join();
   t2.join();
 }

 return 0;
}
```

However you will only realistically get any parallelism on the bits done in the before/after blocks in the loop of `fun1()` and `fun2()`.

You could further increase parallelism by introducing more locks.
For example you can maybe get away with only 2 mutexes which control odd and even elements:

```
void fun1(std::vector<int>&v,std::mutex& mtx0,std::mutex& mtx1 ){
    for(size_t i{0};i<v.size();++i){
        {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(i%2==0?mtx0:mtx1);
            //read-write *v[i]
        }
    } 
}
```

With a similar format for `fun2()`.

You might be able to reduce contention by working from opposite ends of the vectors or using `try_lock` and moving onto subsequent elements and 'coming back' to the locked element when available.

That can be most significant if the execution of an iteration of one function is much greater than the other and there's some advantage in getting the results from the 'faster' one before the other finishes.

Alternatives:

It's obviously possible to add an `std::mutex` to each object.
Whether that works / is necessary will depend on what is actually done in the functions `fun1` and `fun2` as well as how those mutexes are managed.

If it's necessary to lock before either of the loops start there may be in fact no benefit in parallelism because one of `fun1()` or `fun2()` will essentially wait for the other to finish and the two will in effect run in series.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I will lock just some parts of the functions because the sections where data races could occur are quite limited. 
There is still something bugging me in the process of locking with mutexes: if I lock a vector of pointers, is it the memory _pointed_ or the memory where the vector is stored or both to be locked?

Comment: @RiccardoGiubilato Great. That's what I was trying to get over - the you want to restrict locking to where it's needed. It's up to you what has been locked! Your design determines what the lock governs and then you have to implement respecting that principle. So if you say the objects are locked its the objects and you need to make sure you don't change the objects without holding the lock. You might (or not) have another lock to change the pointers and another to change the structure of the vector or one lock over all of them...

Comment: @RiccardoGiubilato Do look at the documentation but remember there are some concurrency guarantees on `std::shared_ptr<>`. Also so long as you don't change the size of `std::vector<>` two threads can read it at once and (with appropriate locking in place) change different members concurrently. It's not clear if you really need `w`  & `v` or if one `std::vector<>` will do.

Comment: @RiccardoGiubilato The section here on 'Thread Safety' should help. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container